# Searching for a file in all directories

Tags: c#

I need to find the file and also return the address of the file. I already tried, but it does not work.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

I was using this code:

```
 var files = new List<string>();
 //@Stan R. suggested an improvement to handle floppy drives...
 //foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
 foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.IsReady == true))
 {
    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(d.RootDirectory.FullName, actualFile, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *"address of the file"* and what *does not work* because `Directory.GetFiles` [returns the names of files (including their paths) ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I used the code I placed above. What happens is that it returns the name to me no more. I need to get the address (Example: c: / Program Files) but it does not leave me already and tried to place this:

All previous code ------ .GetPath

Or something similar but will not let me, syntax error appears.

Comment: If you need other properties than name and path, you should use [DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383457(v=vs.110).aspx) which will return [FileSystemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx) objects instead of strings.

Comment: The result is in the `files` variable. So if you want to see the result, iterate over the files variable after the search.

Comment: Wait. I do not understand, can you explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a quick test and Directory.GetFiles does return the entire path (what you're calling address) to the file.  The Microsoft documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) says it returns:

An array of the full names (**including paths**) for the files in the specified directory, or an empty array if no files are found.

If you still need the complete FileInfo, you could do something like this... (There are more elegant ways, but this will get you want you want.)

```
var files = new List<string>();
foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.IsReady == true))
{
    var matchingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(d.RootDirectory.FullName, actualFile, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    foreach (var matchedFile in matchingFiles)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(matchedFile);

        // The newly created fileInfo will have everything you need, including path inside the FullName
        files.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. I knew about FileInfo but did not know how to do it to return the file path, I thought "FullName" was something else. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, it looks like I have a problem with the code.

But it does not return the file path, but the visual studio project yes. The file (at the moment "Bien.txt") is located in "Local Disk C / Program Files"
 And returns me this path: C: \ Users \ Stiven \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2010 \ Projects \ SIAM Phase 4 Project \ bin \ Debug \ Bien.txt with the "FullName"

Comment: string textoBuscar = UltimaAccion;
                DirectoryInfo directorio = new DirectoryInfo(DiscoD1);
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(textoBuscar);

                var files = new List<string>();
                //@Stan R. suggested an improvement to handle floppy drives...
                //foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
                foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.IsReady == true))
                {
                    try
                    {

Comment: files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(d.RootDirectory.FullName, textoBuscar, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
                         var matchingFiles = files;
                        foreach (var matchedFile in matchingFiles){
                        fileInfo = new FileInfo(matchedFile);
                        }
                        
                    }
                    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException) 
                        {
                    if(files.ToString() == textoBuscar){
                    }

Comment: TXTTextoSiam.Text = fileInfo.FullName + Environment.NewLine + fileInfo.DirectoryName;
                    }
                }

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to provide you with guidance on solving your coding issues, not write code for you.  The code above works - I tested it.  There are some things that do not make sense with your question.  Per the MS documentation, Directory.GetFiles does return the full path to a file: An array of the full names (including paths) for the files in the specified directory, or an empty array if no files are found. It's not really cool to mark an answer correct and then reverse your selection based on a bug in your code.